# How to use .NET Core secrets in .sh file that is called from docker-compose

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-2019, user-secret

**Background**

I am writing a `.NET 5` application and using .net user secrets for my secret keys (database connections & passwords).

Recently I decided to learn `Dockers` and update my application to work with it so that using `Visual Studio` I generated a `docker` file for my `API` project and then created a `docker-compose` file that includes the `API` project & database (and some more irrelevant things for this question).

Almost everything works well. Technically, I can hard-code the secrets, and then the application will work well.

I have some secrets and most of them work fine, e.g: the database connection secrets works well, in the `C#` code I do the following code and it gets the value from the `.net user-secrets`:

```cs
config.GetConnectionString("Default");
```

**Code Details**

I have a secret key that contains a `SQL` password for the `sa` user.

```cs
dotnet user-secrets set "SA_PASSWORD" "<MySecretPassword>"
```

Then I have the `docker-compose` file which is of Linux system and this is part of the code:

```yaml
sql_in_dc:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: items/sql/sql.Dockerfile
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "1440:1433"
  environment:
    - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    - SA_PASSWORD=$SA_PASSWORD
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - USER_SECRETS_ID=80a155b1-fb7a-44de-8788-4f5759c60ff6
  volumes:
    - $APPDATA/Microsoft/UserSecrets/$USER_SECRETS_ID:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets/$USER_SECRETS_ID
    - $HOME/.microsoft/usersecrets/$USER_SECRETS_ID:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets/$USER_SECRETS_ID
```

As you can see it calls the `sql.Dockerfile` which is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server 

ARG PROJECT_DIR=/tmp/devdatabase
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR
COPY items/sql/InitializeDatabase.sql ./
COPY items/sql/wait-for-it.sh ./
COPY items/sql/entrypoint.sh ./
COPY items/sql/setup.sh ./

CMD ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

Then the `setup.sh` is:

```sh
# Wait for SQL Server to be started and then run the sql script
./wait-for-it.sh sql_in_dc:1433 --timeout=0 --strict -- sleep 5s && \
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -i InitializeDatabase.sql -U sa -P "$SA_PASSWORD"
```

**The Problem**

The file `setup.sh` doesn't recognizes the `$SA_PASSWORD` environment variable when it comes from the secrets file.

It works well if I change the `docker-compose.yml` file to:

```yaml
- SA_PASSWORD=SomePassword
```

**Notes**

- I searched for an answer in Google and tried many things but couldn't find exactly my case.
- I know it is possible to use `Docker Swarm` for the secrets but for now I want to do it without it. I am still learning and prefer that the code will work good and the next step will be to use `Docker Swarm` / `Kubernetes` / etc...
- I would be happy to know if there is a fast solution even if it is not the ideal one. Later I will improve it and use better techniques.
- I wrote the code I think that should be enough for the case and the relevant code, but if you need any more data, let me know and I will add it.
- I have it in GitHub in a public repository in a pushed branch. If you want I can share with you the code.

Really big thanks in advance!

Comment: as you mentioned, it is depending on your environment (Docker swarm, Kubernetes). I use a usersecrets for local development in production i create secrets in openshift (kubernetes) and map them into environment variables in the cluster

Comment: @kraego Yes. The problem that for local development. It doesn't recognize the user secrets of `SA_PASSWORD`. Maybe I am not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker-compose.yml` is executed on your **host OS** (so it can use OS environment variables or vars from .env file, or from compose file, ...).
The running image - **container has it's own set of env variables**, in your case that means the running container has no SA_PASSWORD variable.
Your usecase would work if you had set the SA_PASSWORD Variable on your host OS.

You can check which variables are set in your container with (if your image comes with bash):

```sh
docker exec -it [container id] bash
printenv
```

The dotnet-secrets environment variables are created implicit during execution/runtime from Visual Studio (see entry in project file).

So as you mentioned **"the compose file can't recognize dotnet-secrets"**.

You can use:

1. [*.env File](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)
2. pass it to compose command: with `-e`
3. Plain text in `compose yml`: `- SA_PASSWORD=thepassword`
4. as host OS Variable

Keep in mind that Visual Studio adds some magic when running or debugging your docker container. [See Visual Studio container volume mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019#volume-mapping): `For ASP.NET core web apps, there might be two additional folders for the SSL certificate and the user secrets, which is explained in more detail in the next section.`

Comment: Yep, that's what I did until I get an answer here and it works. But still, I don't understand how the connection strings are passed from user secrets to the code which runs in docker-compose in my local environment and it works fine, but the SA_PASSWORD is not?

Comment: Do you mean all other environment variables are present? Just SA_PASSWORD is missing?

Comment: I mean that in my user secrets I have secrets for connection strings and for `SA_PASSWORD` as well. When running the application with docker and the code runs in the `Startup.cs` => I am injecting the connection string which takes it from the `user-secrets` and it manages to read this data properly. But when I try to get the SA_PASSWORD data in the `setup.sh` script, it doesn't recognize it. So, it does recognizes some of the secrets that come from the `user-secrets`. The issue is that it recognizes the SA_PASSWORD when doing it from code (next message will continue...)

Comment: The problem is when trying to read it in my docker-compose file. So with environment variables, it worked well. But why `SA_PASSWORD` is known in the `Startup.cs` which runs under `docker-compose up` command but it doesn't recognizes it if I put it to `docker-compose`.yml file? So maybe, the answer is just that yml file can't recognize dotnet-secrets and that's fine if this is the case.

Comment: For now I am reading the articles. Maybe it will help me understand. +1 from me and maybe will accept this answer soon :) Thanks and will be happy also if you can answer the question above.

Comment: I've rewrote the answer due to your infos :)

Comment: Still not sure about something.. I just debugged my application when running in `docker-compose up`... I see that it is contained in the environment variables list and it comes from the user-secrets. In the Startup.cs I tried to do: `_config["SA_PASSWORD"]` and it found the password. So it means that it comes from user-secrets and works well. When I am doing in the `docker-compose.yml` file SA_PASSWORD=${SA_PASSWORD} it doesn't recognizes it when it comes from user-secrets. Just want to make sure the following question:

Comment: Is it as expected that `user-secret` will be found in `Startup.cs` but not in `docker-compose.yml`? Or I just don't do something wrong with the `.yml` file? I would expect that if it recognizes the variable in `Startup.cs` then it should also recognize it in the `.yml` file. And as I mentioned before, it works well if I write the password in `.env` file - then it recognizes it in `.yml` and this is the solution I did for now. But still not sure why it doesn't recognize from `user-secrets` when it does in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: And maybe you already answered me but I am not sure, sorry. Will be happy if you can explain this.